# how can i get disk space with decimal point in gb tb and mb

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to get the disk space in if it is MB GB or TB with 2 decimal part.
It should give the output with decimals

Here is my code:

```
WMIC LOGICALDISK GET Name,Size,FreeSpace | find /i "C:"
```

Comment: if powershell is possible use [this](http://superuser.com/q/468782/241386)

Comment: can I get in batch script

Comment: Please do not multi-post the same question, you already asked for the same here: [folder size in gbwith 2 decimal points](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37292932)!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the slightly modified script from my answer to another question, which constitutes a pure [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) solution: [Get size of a directory in 'MB' using batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36318398).

Basically, all computations are done with numbers padded by two zeros to the right, which is the same as multiplying by a hundred, and the decimal separator is inserted next to the second digit from the right just for displaying. The drive to get the free space of needs to be given as a command line argument, like `C:` for example.

Here is the code:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Define constants here:
set /A DIVISOR=1024 & rem (1024 Bytes = 1 KiB, 1024 KiB = 1 MiB,...)
set "ROUNDUP=" & rem (set to non-empty value to round up results)
set /A DECIMALS=2 & rem (define number of decimal places here)

set "PAD=" & for /L %%N in (1,1,%DECIMALS%) do call set "PAD=%%PAD%%0"
rem Get free space size of drive given as command line argument:
for /F "tokens=2 delims== " %%B in ('
    wmic LogicalDisk WHERE 'DeviceID^="%~1"' GET FreeSpace /VALUE
') do for /F %%A in ("%%B") do set "BYTES=%%A"
if not defined BYTES set "BYTES=0"
rem Display result in Bytes and divide it to get KiB, MiB, etc.:
call :DIVIDE %BYTES%%PAD% 1 RESULT
call :DISPLAY %RESULT% %DECIMALS% STRING
echo(  Bytes:    %STRING%
call :DIVIDE %RESULT% %DIVISOR% RESULT REST
if defined ROUNDUP if 0%REST% GTR 0 set /A RESULT+=1
call :DISPLAY %RESULT% %DECIMALS% STRING
echo(KiBytes:    %STRING%
call :DIVIDE %RESULT% %DIVISOR% RESULT REST
if defined ROUNDUP if 0%REST% GTR 0 set /A RESULT+=1
call :DISPLAY %RESULT% %DECIMALS% STRING
echo(MiBytes:    %STRING%
call :DIVIDE %RESULT% %DIVISOR% RESULT REST
if defined ROUNDUP if 0%REST% GTR 0 set /A RESULT+=1
call :DISPLAY %RESULT% %DECIMALS% STRING
echo(GiBytes:    %STRING%
call :DIVIDE %RESULT% %DIVISOR% RESULT REST
if defined ROUNDUP if 0%REST% GTR 0 set /A RESULT+=1
call :DISPLAY %RESULT% %DECIMALS% STRING
echo(TiBytes:    %STRING%

endlocal
exit /B


:DIVIDE val_dividend val_divisor [ref_result] [ref_remainder]
rem Divide a huge number exceeding the 32-bit limitation
rem by a 32-bit number in the range from 1 to 1000000000;
rem the result might also exceed the 32-bit limitation.
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "DIVIDEND=%~1"
set "DIVISOR=%~2"
set "QUOTIENT=%~3"
set "REMAINDER=%~4"

rem Check whether dividend and divisor are given:
if not defined DIVIDEND (
    >&2 echo(Too few arguments, dividend missing^^!
    exit /B 2
) else if not defined DIVISOR (
    >&2 echo(Too few arguments, divisor missing^^!
    exit /B 2
)
rem Check whether dividend is purely numeric:
for /F "tokens=* delims=0123456789" %%N in ("!DIVIDEND!") do (
    if not "%%N"=="" (
        >&2 echo(Dividend must be numeric^^!
        exit /B 2
    )
)
rem Convert divisor to numeric value without leading zeros:
for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%N in ("%DIVISOR%") do set "DIVISOR=%%N"
set /A DIVISOR+=0
rem Check divisor against its range:
if %DIVISOR% LEQ 0 (
    >&2 echo(Divisor value must be positive^^!
    exit /B 1
) else if %DIVISOR% GTR 1000000000 (
    >&2 echo(Divisor value exceeds its limit^^!
    exit /B 1
)
set "COLL=" & set "NEXT=" & set /A INDEX=0
rem Do a division digit by digit as one would do it on paper:
:LOOP
if "!DIVIDEND:~%INDEX%,1!"=="" goto :CONT
set "NEXT=!NEXT!!DIVIDEND:~%INDEX%,1!"
rem Remove trailing zeros as such denote octal numbers:
for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%N in ("!NEXT!") do set "NEXT=%%N"
set /A NEXT+=0
set /A PART=NEXT/DIVISOR
set "COLL=!COLL!!PART!"
set /A NEXT-=PART*DIVISOR
set /A INDEX+=1
goto :LOOP
:CONT
rem Remove trailing zeros as such denote octal numbers:
for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%N in ("%COLL%") do set "COLL=%%N"
if not defined COLL set "COLL=0"
rem Set return variables or display result if none are given:
if defined QUOTIENT (
    if defined REMAINDER (
        endlocal
        set "%REMAINDER%=%NEXT%"
    ) else (
        endlocal
    )
    set "%QUOTIENT%=%COLL%"
) else (
    endlocal
    echo(%COLL%
)
exit /B


:DISPLAY val_number val_decimals [ref_result]
rem Prepare fractional number for being displayed.
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "NUM=%~1"
set "DEC=%~2"
set "SEP=."
set "RET=%~3"
set "PAD=" & for /L %%N in (1,1,%DEC%) do set "PAD=!PAD!0"
set "NUM=%PAD%%NUM%"
set "NUM=!NUM:~,-%DEC%!%SEP%!NUM:~-%DEC%!"
for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%N in ("%NUM%") do set "NUM=%%N"
if "%NUM:~,1%"=="%SEP%" set "NUM=0%NUM%"
if defined RET (
    endlocal
    set "%RET%=%NUM%"
) else (
    endlocal
    echo(%NUM%
)
endlocal
exit /B
```

Here is a sample output (supposing the script is saved as `drive-size.bat`):

> ```
> C:\TEMP>drive-size.bat C:
>   Bytes:    82752724992.00
> KiBytes:    80813208.00
> MiBytes:    78919.14
> GiBytes:    77.06
> TiBytes:    0.07
> ```