# Convert 'wmic computersystem get totalphysicalmemory /Value' into megabyte (MB) format

Tags: batch-file, cmd

These are my .bat scripts.

```
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims==" %%a in ('wmic computersystem get totalphysicalmemory /Value') do set /a "mem=%%b/1024/1024"
echo %mem%
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get size of a directory in 'MB' using batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36301198/get-size-of-a-directory-in-mb-using-batch-file). Also related is [how can i get disk space with decimal point in gb tb and mb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37316364/how-can-i-get-disk-space-with-decimal-point-in-gb-tb-and-mb) and [Batch script doesn't run, although its code runs in CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51090280) (ignore the misleading title here).

Answer (score 2):

The question uses `/1024/1024` so I assume that we want the memory size in mebibytes (= 2^20 bytes). If we want decimal megabytes then of course all we neeed to do is to discard the last 6 digits.

```
    @echo off

    setlocal

    set "mem="
    for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (
      'wmic computersystem get totalphysicalmemory /value'
    ) do for /f "delims=" %%b in (
      "%%~a"
    ) do if not defined mem set "mem=%%~b"

::  At this point %mem% is the memory size in bytes. In order to convert to
::  mebibytes we need to divide by 2^20. However, set /a cannot work with
::  numbers greater than 2^31-1; we first convert to decimal megabytes and then
::  multiply by 0.95346.
::  (This will underestimate the mebibytes a little, by about 0.025%.)

    set "memMB=%mem:~0,-6%"
    set /a "mem=((memMB-memMB/21) + (memMB-memMB/22))/2"

    echo This computer has %mem% MiB RAM
```

- `tokens=2` because the result returned by `wmic` looks like

  ```
  TotalPhysicalMemory=25697566720
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^
  1st token           2nd token
  ```
- First `set` and then `set /a` because `for /f` will include a carriage-return in the token, and trying to use it directly with `set /a` will generate an error.
- `set /a` works in 32-bit two's complement arithmentic, so if `%mem%` is greater than 2147483647 we cannot simply compute `%mem%` / 1024 / 1024.

Comment: This works only for values < 2 GiB due to 32-bit limitation of CMD's integer arithmetics...

Comment: @aschipfl: Thank you for the timely reminder. I included a workaround.

Comment: @AlexP Thanks alex! That helped! Im new to batchfile scripting. Would like to ask what does the '~' represent?

Comment: `for /?` and `set /?` will help you understand notations like `"%%~a` and `%mem:~0,6%`.

Comment: Why not use powershell to do the math ? Eg  For /F "Tokens=1" %%I in ('powershell -command "[Math]::Floor([decimal]((%TOTAL_PHYSICAL_MEMORY%/4)*3)/1024/1024)"') Do Set VBOX_PHYSICAL_MEMORY=%%I