# batch command to find a particular folder size

Tags: batch-file, command

I'm trying to find the size a particular folder say 'log' inside my current directory. please suggest me the batch commands used only to retrieve the size of the 'log' folder.

Comment: Related: [Folder list and its sizes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37190069).

Answer (score 0):

i suggesting one window command it display recursively all file size and last line show total size of folder

"dir /S log"

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('dir /s /-c log\^|findstr /b /c:"    "') do (
  for /f "tokens=1" %%b in ("%%a") do set x=%%b& goto :done
)
:done
echo %x% Bytes in this folder (and subfolders)
```

Token(s) might be needed to be adapted to local language.

Comment: I'd add the `/-C` option to `dir` so there is no more need to remove (locale-dependent) thousand separators explicitly...

Comment: @aschipfl ah - I didn't think about `/-c`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (Batch/Vbscript) file :

```dos
@echo off
Title Get Size of Folder and its subfolders
set "Folder=C:\log"
Set Log=Folder_Size.txt 
(
    echo The size of "%Folder%" is 
    Call :GetSize "%Folder%"
)> "%Log%"
For /f "delims=" %%a in ('Dir "%Folder%" /AD /b /s') do ( 
    (
        echo The size of "%%a" is 
        Call :GetSize "%%a"
    )>> "%Log%"
)
start "" "%Log%"
::***********************************************************************
:GetSize
(
echo wscript.echo GetSize("%~1"^)
echo Function GetSize(MyFolder^)
echo    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^)
echo    Set objFolder= fso.GetFolder(MyFolder^)  
echo    GetSize = FormatSize(objFolder.Size^)
echo End Function
echo '*******************************************************************
echo 'Function to format a number into typical size scales
echo Function FormatSize(iSize^)
echo    aLabel = Array("bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB"^)
echo    For i = 0 to 4
echo        If iSize ^> 1024 Then
echo            iSize = iSize / 1024
echo        Else
echo            Exit For
echo        End If
echo    Next
echo    FormatSize = Round(iSize,2^) ^& " " ^& aLabel(i^)
echo End Function
echo '*******************************************************************
)>%tmp%\Size.vbs
Cscript /NoLogo %tmp%\Size.vbs
Del %tmp%\Size.vbs
Exit /b
::***********************************************************************
```

***Edit : On 27/09/2016*** Just for one folder and no recursive :

```dos
@echo off
mode con cols=67 lines=5 & Color 0A
Title Get Size of Folder and its subfolders
set "Folder=C:\HackooTest"
Set Log=%Folder%_Size.txt 
(
    echo The size of "%Folder%" is 
    Call :GetSize "%Folder%"
)> "%Log%"

echo The size of "%Folder%" is 
Call :GetSize "%Folder%"
pause & Start "" "%Log%"
exit
::***********************************************************************
:GetSize
(
echo wscript.echo GetSize("%~1"^)
echo Function GetSize(MyFolder^)
echo    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^)
echo    Set objFolder= fso.GetFolder(MyFolder^)  
echo    GetSize = FormatSize(objFolder.Size^)
echo End Function
echo '*******************************************************************
echo 'Function to format a number into typical size scales
echo Function FormatSize(iSize^)
echo    aLabel = Array("bytes", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB"^)
echo    For i = 0 to 4
echo        If iSize ^> 1024 Then
echo            iSize = iSize / 1024
echo        Else
echo            Exit For
echo        End If
echo    Next
echo    FormatSize = Round(iSize,2^) ^& " " ^& aLabel(i^)
echo End Function
echo '*******************************************************************
)>%tmp%\Size.vbs
Cscript /NoLogo %tmp%\Size.vbs
Del %tmp%\Size.vbs
Exit /b
::***********************************************************************
```

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion. Here i'm getting the size of all individual folders and sub folders inside log folder. My actual requirement is to get a single word output where it displays the log folder size as a whole only. Can you give a suggestion here?

Comment: with the last edit code i get this below: it shows the hardcoded string 'The size of path/folder is ' but not the size value.